# Can I omit ‘to’ after ‘and’?

Tags: infinitives, ellipsis

For example

1. I want to go and leave you.
2. I want to go and to leave you.

Which one would be accurate?

Comment: A better way would be *"I don't want to be with you anymore"*, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I want to leave you, and go.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is wrong, certainly not for common use of English. The second sentence is a much less common construction, in my experience as a native speaker in the United States.

The first sentence suggests that both actions are combined in some way:

> I want to go, and by going I will leave you.

Or, rephrased:

> I want to leave you, which I will do by going.

The second suggests that the speaker wants to do both things, specifically:

> I want to go, and I also want to leave you.

---

There is also a common use of the phrase *go and* which usually does not convey much information other than that someone chose to do something:

> Why did you go and do that?

In those cases *go and* could be completely omitted and the meaning of the sentence would not really change at all. I don't think that that pattern is in place in the first sentence in the question, but I wanted to distinctly mention it because it's likely that you will come across this specific usage of *go and* at some point.